# serviceNotFoundError: Cannot determine a class of the requesting service soap

Tags: node.js, typescript, soap, definitelytyped

I was using soap version 0.26.0, and everything was running fine. Then since upgrading to 0.27.0+ I getting issues with typedi.

I was testing the app like this,

```
beforeAll(() => {
  soapClientStub = {
    LoginAsync: sinon.stub(),
    addUserAsync: sinon.stub(),
    enableUserAsync: sinon.stub(),
    addUserToSpaceAsync: sinon.stub(),
    addUserToGroupInSpaceAsync: sinon.stub(),
    setDashboardViewAsync: sinon.stub(),
    setDenyAddSpaceAsync: sinon.stub(),
    addHttpHeader: sinon.stub(),
    lastResponseHeaders: [],
    setEndpoint: sinon.stub(),
  };

  Container.set(soap.Client, soapClientStub);
  client = Container.get(soap.Client);
});
```

Now, I am unable to get the soap client from the container. typedi is throwing an error saying,

```
serviceNotFoundError: Cannot determine a class of the requesting service
```

I am using typedi version 0.8.0